# Book in which a girl tries to fix the ozone hole with her magic fixing powers

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I was discussing what ozone is recently, and remembered it being a plot point in a kids or young-adult book I read in the late 90s or early 00s. I read this in Australia and this is likely an Australian book.

The main character was a young girl who had the magical ability to fix things that she touched. (I think it may have been part of a series starring this girl.)

In the story in question, she is recruited by a scientist who takes her up in a special craft to attempt to repair the ozone hole with her powers. The craft has holes that she can put her hands or fingers out of because her powers require her to be in contact with the thing she is fixing.

This twist of this plot line (and the reason I was trying to track it down for my kids) is that when she attempts to fix the ozone layer she actually starts converting ozone to oxygen gas, because it turns out that her powers consider ozone to be “broken” oxygen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wonder if this is [*Astrid Spark, Fixologist*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?33137) (2002) by Justin D'Ath.

[image: Cover of "Astrid Spark, Fixologist" showing Astrid leaning out the window of the bagggoon]

The blurb from Google books reads:

> Astrid Spark has an extraordinary gift - she can fix broken things. But when eccentric CSIRO scientist, Dr Augustus Hu, dreams up a fix for the hole in the ozone layer, Astrid becomes involved in a perilous balloon adventure that tests more than her fixologist's skills.

Note that CSIRO is an Australian organization, which locates the story to Australia.

The Goodreads blurb has a bit more:

> Astrid Spark has an incredible gift—**her fingers can fix anything that is broken**. More important, her magnetic fingers might just be able to **fix the hole in the ozone layer**. The tale unfolds with great inventiveness, comedy, and lively illustrations, as Astrid’s friends not only learn about the environment and the fragile ozone, but also build a special vehicle to catapult her into the stratosphere, a bagggoon. Yet will Astrid’s fingers be able to fix something as large as the ozone?

It is the second book (of two) featuring Astrid after [*Echidna Mania*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?269208) (2001).